# Is it possible to use abstract classes or interfaces in laravel Policies (Gates)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to use abstract classes or interfaces in laravel Policies (Gates)? Like this:

```
protected $policies = [
    MyAbstractClass::class => PostPolicy::class,
    MyInterface::class => PostPolicy::class,
];
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected $policies = [
    AbstractClass::class => ConcreteClass::class,
    PostAbstractClass::class => PostConcreteClass::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L504) for `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate` falls back to `is_subclass_of()` when resolving a Policy instance. From the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php) for `is_subclass_of()`:

> Checks if the given object has the class class_name as one of its
>   parents **or implements** it.

(emphasis mine)

So yes, you should be able to do that.